# Select var text and set styling

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I am trying to select some text and bold it for when the slider advances to the next slide. I have the "**Showing 1** out of 3" but when you cycle through it is not bold on the cycle. I would like to make sure the "showing #" is always bold. Here is my current code.

```
<div id="carousel-index" style="text-align: left;"><b>Showing 1</b> out of 3</div>

<script>

$('.Leadership').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {


  var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');

  var currentIndex = carouselData.getItemIndex(carouselData.$element.find('.item.active'));
  var total = carouselData.$items.length;

  var text = " Showing " + (currentIndex + 1) + " out of " + total;

  $('#carousel-index').text(text);
});

</script>
```

Comment: This should be bootstrap 3 not twitter-bootstrap by the way.

Comment: I now have it close but I am not sure how to wrap a certain part of this with a span id myP please help. 

$('.Leadership').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

  var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');

  var currentIndex = carouselData.getItemIndex(carouselData.$element.find('.item.active'));
  var total = carouselData.$items.length;


  var text = "Showing " + (currentIndex + 1) + " out of " + total;

  $('#carousel-index').text(text);
});
document.getElementById('myP').style.cssText = 'font-weight:bold;';

Comment: The document.getElementById is making the <div id="carousel-index" style="text-align: left;"><span id="myP">Showing 1</span> out of 3</div> Showing 1 bold but as soon as I click the next or previous button the javascript takes over and is not bold looping through. How do I wrap the Showing # in a span with an id of myP?

Comment: Basically I need something like this don't I

var span = '<span id="myP">';
var text = "Showing " + (currentIndex + 1) + "</span>" + " out of " + total;

The closing span shows up though and the span I create nevers gets added. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured this out the other day and was pretty embarrassed to post the fix:

Changing this $('#carousel-index').text(text);
To this: $('#carousel-index').html(text);

```
<div id="carousel-index" style="text-align: left;"><b>Showing 1</b> out of 3</div>
```

$('.Leadership').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {


  var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');

  var currentIndex = carouselData.getItemIndex(carouselData.$element.find('.item.active'));
  var total = carouselData.$items.length;

  var text = " Showing " + (currentIndex + 1) + " out of " + total;

  $('#carousel-index').html(text);
});

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

var text = "< b >Showing " + (currentIndex + 1) + "< / b > out of " + total;

Then "Showing #" is always bold

Comment: This does not work. I did try this but it keeps the tags and displays:

<b> Showing 2</b> out of 3

Comment: I just tried this and it wraps the results with <b></b> but it is not adding to the styling just adds the characters to the results

  var text = text.bold();

Results = <b> Showing 3 out of 3</b>